# Fetch specific distinct columns from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have 2 tables:

**Table A:**

```
ID | Date      | Uploaded Date
---+-----------+--------------
16 | 05/01/2020| 05/05/2020 12:36 PM
18 | 05/01/2020| 05/05/2020 12:20 PM
```

**Table B:**

```
ID | Value | Amount  | A_ID
---+-------+---------+-----
1  | 3     | 76.295  | 16
2  | 2     | 93.465  | 16
3  | 5     | 82.396  | 16
4  | 8     | 62.2736 | 16
5  | 9     | 50.71   | 16
6  | 3     | 75.869  | 18
7  | 2     | 93.465  | 18
8  | 5     | 82.396  | 18
9  | 8     | 62.2736 | 18
10 | 9     | 50.71   | 18
```

I am trying to write a `select` statement which fetches unique data based on condition.

What I am looking for is unique record based on value column. FYR - below output:

```
Date       | Amount  | Value
---+-------+---------+------
05/01/2020 | 76.295  | 3
05/01/2020 | 93.465  | 2
05/01/2020 | 82.396  | 5
05/01/2020 | 62.2736 | 8
05/01/2020 | 50.71   | 9
```

Below are few queries that I have tried:

```
select Date, Amount, Value
from A
left join B on A.ID = B.A_ID  order by Uploaded Date desc
```

After executing above query I get the below data:

```
Date       | Amount  | Value
---+-------+---------+------
05/01/2020 | 76.295  | 3
05/01/2020 | 93.465  | 2
05/01/2020 | 82.396  | 5
05/01/2020 | 62.2736 | 8
05/01/2020 | 50.71   | 9
05/01/2020 | 75.869  | 3
05/01/2020 | 93.465  | 2
05/01/2020 | 82.396  | 5
05/01/2020 | 62.2736 | 8
05/01/2020 | 50.71   | 9
```

I tried `distinct` query:

```
select distinct Date, Amount, Value
from A
left join B on a.ID = b.A_ID order by uploaded date desc
```

but it stills return me duplicate data:

```
Date       | Amount  | Value
---+-------+---------+------
05/01/2020 | 76.295  | 3
05/01/2020 | 93.465  | 2
05/01/2020 | 82.396  | 5
05/01/2020 | 62.2736 | 8
05/01/2020 | 50.71   | 9
05/01/2020 | 75.869  | 3
```

Table with Multiple records.

```
ID | Date      | Uploaded Date
---+-----------+--------------
16 | 05/01/2020| 05/05/2020 12:36 PM
18 | 05/01/2020| 05/05/2020 12:20 PM
19 | 05/02/2020| 05/05/2020 12:43 PM
20 | 05/03/2020| 06/05/2020 11:57 AM
21 | 05/04/2020| 06/05/2020 11:57 AM
```

```
ID | Value | Amount  | A_ID
---+-------+---------+-----
1  | 3     | 76.295  | 16
2  | 2     | 93.465  | 16
3  | 3     | 82.396  | 16
4  | 8     | 62.2736 | 16
5  | 3     | 50.71   | 19
6  | 3     | 50.51   | 20
7  | 4     | 52.71   | 21
8  | 4     | 55.11   | 20
```

In this case the o/p I am hoping for :

```
Date       | Amount  | Value
---+-------+---------+------
05/01/2020 | 76.295  | 3
05/01/2020 | 93.465  | 2
05/01/2020 | 62.2736 | 8
05/02/2020 | 50.71   | 3
05/03/2020 | 50.51   | 3
05/03/2020 | 55.11   | 4
05/04/2020 | 52.71   | 4
```

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: It's behaving exactly as expected as amount differs.

It might be that you want to have a max(value) or something like that but you really need to provide more data

Comment: I need distinct data based on the value column

Comment: New user. Will keep the image and formatted text in mind next time.

Comment: Why do you want the row with amount = 76.295 and not the row with amount = 75.869?

Comment: I have rates (Amount) which basically gets updated everyday. for e.g. currency rates. I upload the amount along with the date in both the tables. But while fetching the amount on the interface, I just need the latest amount which I have uploaded. I can upload multiple amounts for the same date. Hence need the unique amount along with the date and value field

Comment: How can you tell that the row with amount = 76.295 is the latest?

Comment: I have a uploaded date column in table A which I can use for order by condition

Comment: Then edit your question and add this column also in your sample data.

Comment: I have added the uploaded date column as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correct, you wants the first row only (based on ID) among all rows with same value in the column Value. If it is correct, you can use ROW_NUMBER for achieving your requirement as below-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=656fbc49f3d9fd1dc22b51e348e430b3)

```
SELECT ID,Value,Amount,A_ID 
FROM 
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY ID) RN
    FROM Table_B
)A
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

Now you can join the output with your Table_A to pick other necessary data.

In case you have multiple dates and you need to keep first record per date, the row_number generation will be as below. Other part of query will be just as it is now.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(Date AS Date),Value ORDER BY ID) RN
```

Comment: what if I have records with multiple dates . Have added table above for reference . Would need all records with distinct date and value column. Apologies if requirement not clear. Based on your query would only be able to fetch 1 record for 1 date type

Comment: You can also keep 1 record per date. That case you just need to create the ROW_NUMBER bit differently. I am adding sample code soon.

Comment: Thanks man. That worked. I am getting the exact output as required.

Comment: You are most welcome @Sam. Please don't forget to put an up vote as well  :)